# facing trobule in url-rewriting a dynamic url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am using .htaccess file for URL re-writing and i change the some url like this using .htaccess file :-

```
RewriteRule  ^home/?$ index.php   [NC,L]
```

but i have no idea how i change this url

```
/localhost/mywebiste/complete_listing.php?category=Education&city=delhi
```

into this URL

```
/localhost/mywebiste/education-in-delhi
```

Every category and city in url.

i try this :

```
Rewrite-rule  ^Agriculture-in-jaipur([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ complete_listing.php?category=education&&city=delhi [NC,L]
```

but by this i change only one type URL every time category and city will be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right you want to get /localhost/mywebiste/**education**-in-**delhi** - the url with 2 variables

```
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)-in-([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ complete_listing.php?category=$1&city=$2 [NC,L]
```

Note the `L` on the end - this will be the Last rule applied.

Comment: thanks for help but there is one problem in url category have space,&  its note working who can i remove %20 from url Bike%20Service%20Center-in-Jaipur

Comment: you must strip spaces ie. `$string = str_replace(' ', '', $string);`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)-in-(.*)$ complete_listing.php?category=$1&city=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: thanks for help but there is one problem in url category have space,&  its note working who can i remove %20 from url Bike%20Service%20Center-in-Jaipur

Answer (score 0):

That code will return
http://www.example.com/Education-in-delhi.html

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)-in-([^-]*)\.html$ /mywebiste/complete_listing.php?category=$1&city=$2 [L]
```